# Understanding Chrome dev tools memory snapshot

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using heap snap shot to resolve memory leak. In comparison mode, the Delta show only three constructors -- (compile code), (array), and (system) -- in that decreasing 'Size Delta' order. What do they mean and how do I relate them to code? If I do 'Allocation Timeline", I would see that when memory release is NOT happening (Blue), it would show same Constructor being called. Any suggestion on how can I find offending code would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Chrome v 67.*. I don't see any 'Detached*' object showing delta in my heap snapshot comparison. So it is fair to say I'm not leaking DOM object?